PS5 and PC audio through same speakers, how to?
I've just got myself a new PC setup, and I wanted to integrate my PS5 in it.

Monitor: LG UltraGear 27GP95RP-B (No speakers, with 3.5mm audio out)
Speakers: Logitech Z313 (3.5mm TRS)
Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIXZ790-F GAMING WIFI II (SPDIF out, Line out, Mic in)
The monitor is connected to the PC graphics card via DisplayPort. PS5 uses HDMI.

Currently, the speakers are connected directly to the Line out of the motherboard, so only the PC audio is heard. How can I do to connect both PC and PS5 audio through the speakers without the hassle of changing every time the speaker cable from the PC to the monitor?
I've tried to use a headphone/mic splitter (1 female to 2 males - headphone and mic) without result, as only the headphone part of the splitter carries actual audio.
Thanks in advance!

You could run the console audio to the computer as an input and then use monitor mode to "listen" to the input audio through the speakers, but this will likely introduce significant audio delay. The other method is to use a mixer, which will allow you to independently set volumes for each input and mix them out to the speakers. The mixer is the better solution overall, but requires buying a mixer.

I think there's some kind of KVM-like switcher on the market that is for just analog audio inputs as well. Might be cheaper than a mixer.

To clarify a difference between music2myear and Tom's good ideas: if you want to listen to both sources at the same time, you would need a mixer; I have used a Gemini 2-channel DJ mixer for this. Otherwise, if you don't need to play from both sources concurrently, you could get something like this cheap RCA switcher I've used. (A way more expensive alternative is a home theater AV receiver that switches audio & video between multiple HDMI inputs, but they don't have DP, and 3.5mm line-out to powered speakers like the Z313 is atypically used.)

Thank you all for your answers! As Ben Hutchinson has remarked, I don't need to play both sources at the same time, just switch between them.
Finally, I've settled on this audio switcher from Amazon, which is precisely what I was looking for. An audio mixer was the other alternative I was considering, but most need a mains plug and I'm already struggling with my power strip. But, if I needed to listen to both sources concurrently, that would have been the go-to solution.
